# Batch file - how to exit from loop if folder is empty

Tags: for-loop, ftp, batch-processing

sorry if this is too noob and for my poor english.
I'm struggling on this: I've made a batch that recursively  reads the content of a folder, then creates a script to put the file stored in the variable on an ftp folder and runs it then moves the transfered file on another folder for tracking.
What i need is to stop the batch when the last file is moved and the folder is empty, here's my code:

```
:loop
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "C:\myfolder" ') do set filenamer=%%a
echo open [ftpIPAddress]>ftpscript.ftp
echo [ftpuser]>>ftpscript.ftp
echo [ftppasswd]>>ftpscript.ftp
echo lcd C:\myfolder>>ftpscript.ftp
echo cd [remoteTargetLocation]>>ftpscript.ftp
echo binary>>ftpscript.ftp
echo put %filenamer%>>ftpscript.ftp
echo quit>>ftpscript.ftp
ftp -i -s:ftpscript.ftp
move C:\myfolder\%filenamer% C:\myfolder\sent
TIMEOUT /T 4
goto loop
```

Comment: change in `set "filenamer=" & for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "C:\myfolder" 2^> nul ') do set "filenamer=%%a"` and add `if not defined filenamer goto :eof`

Comment: Hello Einstein, thanks a lot 
I've changed the first line and added the "if not defined..." string
It Actually stops, but in the ftp prompt after the "put" command, what i need to achieve is to close the prompt window when the folder is empty

I'll try to find a way, thanks !